# Birthday paradox for non-uniform probabilities

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, birthday-paradox

Suppose we take draw $k$ IID samples from multinomial distribution
$$\mathbf{p}=p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_d$$

What is the smallest $k$ such that probability of drawing the same class twice is at least 50%?

In numerical simulations, the following appears to be a good fit
$$k\approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\|\mathbf{p}\|^2}}$$
Why?

---

Here's the [simulation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-birthday-problem.nb), I take various distributions and plot the smallest group size at which half the trials get a collision against the value of $R=\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{p}\|^2}$.

[image]

Comment: The good thing is that the formula reduces to the uniform version for $p_i=\frac{1}{d}$ for all $i$.

Comment: I got this formula from Welch-Satterthwaite approximation for degrees of freedom when dimensions are non-uniform, but hoping there's a simpler explanation

Comment: I am not so good at reading your wolframalpha code. Could you explain your simulation in words.

Comment: I take distributions of the form $p_i \propto i^{-c}$ for different values of $c$ and fixed $d=100$. For each distribution I compute the smallest size of the group required for probability of collision to be 50%. Probabilities are estimated empirically over many samples

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach 1

Let's assume that $d$ is large and the distribution of birthdays on day $i$ can be modelled/approximated as independent Poisson variables.

Each day has a frequency of $\lambda_i = n \cdot p_i$ birthdays and the probability of no double birthday on day $i$.

$$P(X_i \leq 1) = e^{-\lambda_i}(1+ \lambda_i)$$

The probability of no double birthday on all days is

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\prod_{i=1}^d e^{-\lambda_i}(1+ \lambda_i) &=& e^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^d (1+ p_i n) \\
& \approx &
 \left(1-n+0.5n^2\right) \left( 1 + n \sum_{i=1}^d  p_i + n^2 \left[ \sum_{\forall i,j} p_i p_j \right]\right) \\
& \approx &
 \left(1-n+0.5n^2\right) \left( 1 + n  + n^2 0.5 \left[ 1- \sum_{\forall i} p_i^2 \right]\right) \\
& \approx &
1 + 0.5 n^2 \sum_{ i = 1}^n p_i^2 \\
\end{array}$$

and to put that equal to $0.5$ leads to

$$n^2  \sum_{ i = 1}^n p_i^2 = 1$$

or

$$n =  \frac{1}{  \sqrt{\sum_{ i = 1}^n p_i^2 }}$$

#### Approach 2

We can convert this in a waiting time problem and consider adding birthdays untill there is a double one. Then the probability to have at least a double birthday among $n$ birthdays is equivalent to 1 minus the probability that we have to wait at least $n$ birthdays untill we have a double birthday.

If the days have equal probabilities then the probability to 'hit a double birthday' is linearly increasing as more and more birthdays are being added

$$P(\text{hit on day $k+1$| no hit yet}) = k/d$$

and the probability of no hits yet is

$$P(\text{ no hit yet on day $k+1$}) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^k (1 - i/d)$$

or

$$\log\left(1-P(\text{ no hit yet on day $k+1$})\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k \log(1 - i/d) \approx \int_0^{k} \log(1-x/d) dx = (k - d)\log(1-k/d) - k \approx -\frac{k^2}{2d}$$

In your case $d=100$ you will get the $0.5$ probability for $k \approx 11.77$, which seems close to the asymptote in your graph.

[image: example image for d = 100]

In the case of equal probabilities of a birthday on a day, we consider this integral $\int_0^{k} \log(1-x/d) dx$ as the probability of at least a double birthday.

With unequal probabilities, the path $ \log(1-x/d)$ will not be fixed and will be stochastic instead. That may cause discrepancies.

Possibly this problem can be solved as a random walk with drift, and each step there is a probability of ending the walk, based on the position of the walk.

Comment: $d$ is held constant, but probability distributions are changing. I sort probability distributions by their value of $R$, to generate the plot in original post. $R$ seems to play the role of $d$ for non-isotropic case. IE, for linear estimation in non-isotropic case, $R$ is the estimate of degrees of freedom equivalent to the Walsh-Satterthwaite approximation

Comment: Note that $1/R$ gives the probability of collision in a random pair of samples

Comment: The quadratic term involves $x^2.$  Wherever any $x$ appears, it is multiplied by a $y.$ Therefore, unless you invoked some kind of algebraic simplifying assumption, your $x^2$ term must be multiplied by a *quadratic form* in the $y_i$ rather than their sum.

Comment: For the waiting problem and uniform distribution over $d$ outcomes, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348365/expected-number-of-drawings-to-find-collision/1348408#1348408) is $\sqrt{\pi d/2}$ which looks a lot like the formula. What is the connection between waiting problem and birthday problem?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov that answer that you link to is for the expectation value of the number of birthdays needed untill we have a double birthday. It also computed/approximates the probability for a specific number and it is $P(k<K) \approx e^{-k^2/(2d)}$ if you put that equal to $0.5$ them you get $$k \approx \sqrt{-2 \log(0.5) d} \approx \sqrt{1.387 d}$$ in my answer I get a factor 1, that might be due to the Poissonation. But at least the $1.387$ is less badly different from my answer than the $\pi/2$.

Comment: Be aware that Poissonization may not be useful here (even for large $n$), because $\lambda$ does not increase with $n$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695752/whats-wrong-in-my-use-of-poissonization-in-this-simple-example

Comment: @leonbloy that's an interesting thought. With smaller $\lambda$ the correlation between the different days becomes bigger. In this question $\lambda$ is not small here, and it does increase, but possibly it's not large enough. The second approach works well though and it shows that there is only a small difference. The second method can, I believe, also be extended to intuitively incorporate the $\sum p_i^2$ term, but I haven't written it out.

Comment: Actually, $\lambda$ does decrease with increasing days, because how  $n \approx  \sqrt{1.387d}$ and $\lambda = n/d \propto \frac{\sqrt{1.387}}{\sqrt{d}}$.

Comment: BTW, summarized simulations for related issue [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2917025) -- TLDR; R gives a good estimate of dimensionality, it underestimates true value by about 1-2%